# Syntax Error with simple google app script api call

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a syntax error with a simple code line of **google sheet app scripts**, I am not experienced in app scripts but this is pretty straight forward syntax from any programming language. Kindly show me if I'm missing something?

I tried changing header into 'header' or "header" but syntax error was on it not recognizing the format

```
function loadInformation(){

  //Set up service and check access
  var firebaseService = getFirebaseService();
  if (firebaseService.hasAccess()) {   
    //Set up google sheet and header row
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("<YOUR SHEETNAME>");
    Sheet.clearContents();
    Sheet.appendRow([<YOUR SHEET HEADERS>]); 

    //Set up reference
    var databaseURL = "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/";
    var ref = "xxxxxx";
    var requestURL = databaseURL+ref+".json";

    //API Call
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestURL, {
     headers: {
       Authorization: 'Bearer ' + firebaseService.getAccessToken()
     },
      method: 'get'
    });

    //Parse JSON
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    //Loop through JSON and append row
    for (item in data){   
      var newRow = [item,];
      Sheet.appendRow(newRow);
    } 
   }  
  } else {

    //Show authorization URL to user
    var authorizationUrl = firebaseService.getAuthorizationUrl();
     showDialog(authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

Error Result :

> **Syntax error. (line 20, file "loadInformation") Dismiss**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "else" is outside the function.  Delete the " } " before the "else".

Also, if this line is left like this it will throw another error.  Be sure to have the headers actually there:

```
    Sheet.appendRow([<YOUR SHEET HEADERS>]);
```

like this:

```
    Sheet.appendRow(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Mark said, your 'else' is outside the function.

And if you change this

```
Sheet.appendRow([<YOUR SHEET HEADERS>]);
```

to

```
Sheet.appendRow(["<YOUR SHEET HEADERS>"]);
```

the syntax error should go away.